# "In" vs. "among"

Tags: grammar

I have read the following sentence in a medical textbook:
"Nosebleeds are also common, but sometimes serious, **in** people over age 50." Would it not be better if we used "among" in place of "in" ?

Comment: Without any hard evidence to back me up, I would suggest that "among" (and "amongst") has (a) become old-fashioned and less used over recent decades, and (b) it tends to be used for physical things ("among the flowers"), or in a few stock phrases, such as "among friends". So "in people over age 50." sounds crisp and modern.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is referring to a pathology that affects individuals, where among is group oriented:  1. surrounded by somebody/something; in the middle of somebody/something: A house among the trees; They strolled among the crowds. 
2.  being included or happening in groups of things or people: A British woman was among the survivors; He was among the last to leave.  3.  used when you are dividing or choosing something, and three or more people or things are involved: They divided the money up among their three children.

In the sentence cited in the question the nosebleed sufferers are related only in a statistical sense.  If the sentence was discussing a meeting of an epistaxis support group then an individual nosebleeder could be said to be "among" a group where many of the members were over 50 years old and suffered frequent nosebleeds and in some, the attacks could be quite serious.

Comment: A vote for your good answer in terms of general usage. Please see my answer about *among* in a medical setting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *among* would be better than *in* in a medical textbook.

In medical writing, *among* is the standard term when reporting on, or even
when merely referring to, a category or group — of
patients, of candidly-observed people, clinical-experiment subjects,
laboratory animals, . . .

The term *in* is used more for specifying a location, as in:

> Lesions **in** the sinus lining are also common, but sometimes serious,
>   **among** people over age 50.

An example of *among* in the title of a recent medical article:

[“Global, national burden of diseases, injuries **among**
 children &
 adolescents.”](http://www.mdlinx.com/otolaryngology/medical-news-article/2016/01/28/6511223/)

 Institute for Health Metrics and Evaluation News, 1/27/2016.

Countless other examples can be found with searches such as:

http://www.mdlinx.com/otolaryngology/search-articles.cfm/among

[Sorry if the above web sites limit the number of
        free searches or views, but you get the idea.]

Comment: I think the original author of that sentence was reporting some facts about the age groups of people who suffer nosebleeding. But, it is not clear,at least for me, if "among" can be a substitute for"in". You are the only person who  agrees with me .

Comment: Countless journal articles agree with you too, @midomido.  Please see my revised answer, which I might revise again now that I saw your comment.

Comment: Great answer. I thought about posting it, but you did.