# 'In' and 'among' of the title of a manuscript, which is appropriate?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, among

I'm writing a manuscript for a medical journal, but I have trouble giving a title of it. The article looks into the effect (severe perineal injury) of episiotomy (a procedure done when delivering a baby) from a certain number of parturients who are all Koreans. I think the title should be

> "Episiotomy and the risk of severe perineal injuries in Korean women".

My colleague thinks that

> "Episiotomy and the risk of severe perineal injuries among Korean women"

is appropriate. Which one is better? 
Please help.

Comment: @human Hi, human. Just for your information, you can always leave a comment to a closed question.

Comment: Related question, [“In” vs. “among”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292289/in-vs-among).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Basically a copy of my [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/305093/153448)
 at [“In” vs. “among”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/292289/153448):]

True, *in* is more appropriate in nonmedical writing but *among* is the standard term for a medical study with multiple subjects.

> Episiotomy and the risk of severe perineal injury **among** Korean women

This would also apply to an overview of studies with multiple subjects,
if that is what you happen to be reporting.

The term *in* is used more specifically for locations, as in
(though not as well worded as above):

> Episiotomy and the risk of severe injury **in** the perineum **among** Korean women

An example of *among* in the title of a recent medical article:

[“Delivery factors associated with fistula location among Malawian women”](http://www.ajog.org/article/S0002-9378%2815%2901598-7/)

American Journal of Obstetrics & Gynecology, Vol. 214, Issue 1, S149–S150, January 2016

Countless other examples can be found with article searches such as:

http://www.ajog.org/action/doSearch?searchType=quick&searchText=among&occurrences=articleTitle&journalCode=ymob&searchScope=fullSite

[Sorry if the above web site limits the number
 of free searches or views, but you get the idea.]

Comment: @HSPark If you find the answer helpful, please click on the check below the downvote button on the left side. Since I upvoted your question, you can even upvote the answer.